# minifying boilerplate code on C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates, dry

suppose I have code like this:

```
template <class T>
class Something{
public:
    int func1();
    int func2();

    T   t;
    int n = 0;
};

template <class T>
int Something<T>::func1(){
   return t.value() * n;
}

template <class T>
int Something<T>::func2(){
   return n;
}
```

In this case `Something::func2()` does not really depends of template parameter T, so it can be compiled into the object file, instead of recompiled every time (this is compiler dependent and can or can not be true).

Second, you still need to type `template <class T> int Something<T>::func2()`.

is there a way to simplify the boilerplate code?

Comment: push that code in to a base class?

Comment: Add a non-template base class and move func1() and func2() there.

Comment: I thought something about pimple...

Comment: @Jojje But `func1` requires access to `t` so it must be templated. `func2` needs access to `n` and it is not generally clear that you can move `n` to a base class.

Comment: Yes @nwp you are right. But func2 and n might be moved, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case Something::func2() does not really depends of template
>   parameter T, so it can be compiled into the object file, instead of
>   recompiled every time (this is compiler dependent and can or can not
>   be true).

No. func2 is a method of class, and since `Something<int>` and `Something<double>` are two different classes, their code should be compiled.

What you can do is extract method from the class, to a separate method or  a base class, but in total, I think you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Object Oriented Programming is here to help you! Make `Something<T>` inherit from an untempletized class `SomethingBase`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct SomethingBase
{
    int un_templatized();
};

int SomethingBase::un_templatized()
{
    return 42;
}

template <class T>
struct Something : SomethingBase
{
    T templetized(T t)
    {
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Something<double> s;
    std::cout << s.un_templatized() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.templetized(3.14) << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcb819edec3be412)</kbd>

Comment: `un_templatized` now returns `42` instead of `Something::n` which seems like a massive limitation of this solution.

Comment: @nwp This is just a minimal example, nothing forbids `SomethingBase` to include an `int` attribute.